# Cron job to call a JSP Page with Javascript

Tags: java, linux, cron

I am developing an Email client using Java Mail API. Now, to regularly check for New Mails, I want to call a page "Synchronize_update.jsp"

I have to do it through a JSP as I need to also execute a piece of JavaScript Code towards the end which is basically an AJAX Call to Notify_all_for_new_mail.jsp.

Can any one suggest me a solution? I am on a Linux Virtual server with command line full access.

Comment: Why can you not execute the AJAX call on the server-side?

Comment: JavaScript is typically run in a browser, whereas a JSP page often is executed on a (web) server. How are you planning to implement this JavaScript/JSP combo? Uhm, I understand that this basically is *your* question, but I am thinking you may have mixed up the languages?

Comment: @myself: Or maybe not. Are you implementing your email client as a web application?

Comment: No matter the client, it can still talk to a service on the other side.  A JSP is not the way to do this.

Comment: @Peter - Yes, I am trying to implement a web based mail client. The new notifications are through a COMET Framework. But I need to send an Update request to this page for Notifying all online users.

Comment: @duffy- Thanks for your idea of rethinking. I converted the JSP page to a class and got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.util.Timer and java.util.TimerTask classes if your scheduling is simple, or use [Quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) if you wish to achieve cron like scheduling.

Here is [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule.html) using Timer.

For emulating browser functionality in your code you can use [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/).

I think using above tools you can achieve your functionality. Hope this helps.